# How do I keep a controller spec and its mocks DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm told this is the correct way to write a controller it block:

```
describe UsersController do
  let(:user){ mock_model(User, id: 2, name: "Jimbo", email: 'jimbo@email.com', password: 'passwordhuzzah', password_confirmation: 'passwordhuzzah') }

  describe 'PATCH #update' do
    it "should fail in this case" do
      User.should_receive(:find).with(user.id.to_s).and_return user      
      user.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({ "email" => user.email, "name" => user.name, "password" => user.password, "password_confirmation" => user.password_confirmation }).and_return true

      patch :update, id: user.id, user: { email: user.email, name: user.name, password: user.password, password_confirmation: user.password_confirmation }

      flash[:error].should == "could not update user"
      response.status.should == 200
    end
  end
end
```

But I am surprised, because it doesn't seem DRY to me. Let's say I want to create two 'contexts' here. One where the `user.update_attributes` call returns false and returns true. Am I meant to simply copy paste two it blocks and tweak that one tiny argument?

```
describe UsersController do
  let(:user){ mock_model(User, id: 2, name: "Jimbo", email: 'jimbo@email.com', password: 'passwordhuzzah', password_confirmation: 'passwordhuzzah') }

    it "should pass in this case" do
      User.should_receive(:find).with(user.id.to_s).and_return user      
      user.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({ "email" => user.email, "name" => user.name, "password" => user.password, "password_confirmation" => user.password_confirmation }).and_return true

      patch :update, id: user.id, user: { email: user.email, name: user.name, password: user.password, password_confirmation: user.password_confirmation }

      flash[:error].should == "updated user"
      response.status.should == 302
    end

    it "should fail in this case" do
      User.should_receive(:find).with(user.id.to_s).and_return user      
      user.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({ "email" => user.email, "name" => user.name, "password" => user.password, "password_confirmation" => user.password_confirmation }).and_return false

      patch :update, id: user.id, user: { email: user.email, name: user.name, password: user.password, password_confirmation: user.password_confirmation }

      flash[:error].should == "could not update user"
      response.status.should == 200
    end
  end
end
```

I was hoping rspec would allow me to write this sort of structure:

```
describe 'PATCH #update' do
   before {} 
   context 'when attributes can be updated' do
         before {}
         it "should set the flash" do end
         it "should set the status" do end
    end
    context 'when attributes can\'t be updated' do
         before {}
         it "should set the status" do end
         it "should set the flash" do end
    end
 end
```

**Note the multiple it blocks for the same contexts, because isn't one expectation per it block a good practise because it allows you to see exactly what's not working? How are you meant to do this with mocks?**

Comment: Why the mock? Can't you use a real User? Seriosuly; RoR's success as the flagship platform for TDD on the Web has lead to a _lot_ of bad practices out there...

Comment: Just to clarify, I said that "creating mocks, setting expectations, performing operation, checking results" was an appropriate flow. The specific code was not intended to be exemplary; it was offered as a minimum-working change to what you started with. :-)

Comment: So when should I actually be using mocks? I thought the idea was to keep controller specs utterly, utterly separate from user specs hence the term `unit spec`. Should I just be mocking certain model methods, then? And use the model's real attributes and relationships? **I just really liked the idea of having one bad expectation so I can see exactly what's been broken, rather than thousands because I accidentally deleted a character in the model file!**

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Ah okay :) But do you agree with Philip that I shouldn't be mocking? I think I raise a valid point for mocking, personally, regarding the thousands of failures?

Comment: I'm not that knowledgable about and don't have a strong opinion about what constitutes "best practice" with respect to controller tests. Such questions are also not a good fit for Stack Overflow (i.e. too much a matter of opinion). There's a lot of opinions out there, though, including: a) Don't write them, b) Write them as functional tests, and c) Write them as unit tests (as you're doing and as described in http://solnic.eu/2012/02/02/yes-you-should-write-controller-tests.html)

Comment: I do hear you, but with something as widely used as rspec, I think the best practise is pretty much set in stone IMHO. Seems like a really good link, thanks :)